# OrderBy on nested collections

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm trying to sort this complex object:

```
Order _sut = new Order
{
    OrderDataArray = new[]
    {
        new OrderData
        {
            OrderHeaderArray = new[]
            {
                new OrderHeader
                {
                    SequenceNumber = 1,
                    OrderPositionArray = new[]
                    {
                        new OrderPositions
                        {
                            LineNumber = 3
                        },
                        new OrderPositions
                        {
                            LineNumber = 2
                        },
                        new OrderPositions
                        {
                            LineNumber = 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Using the code:

```
[Fact]
public void Sorts_By_Sequence_Number()
{
    var ordered = _sut.OrderDataArray
        .OrderBy(o => o.OrderHeaderArray
            .OrderBy(a => a.OrderPositionArray
                .OrderBy(p => p.LineNumber)))
        .ToArray();

    _sut.OrderDataArray = ordered;
    OutputHelper(_sut);
}
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work, meaning the sorting routine simply keeps initial order of `LineNumber` object. I've tried various things with `OrderBy`, but looks like it doesn't sort.

## EDIT

Thank you for responses, both are correct. I have accepted poke's response as it provides a bit more detailed information on the inner workings of the OrderBy method. Basically I was missing the assignment within the loop, I was trying to sort all objects at once.

Comment: What exactly do you want to sort and by which property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider what `OrderBy` does. It orders a collection by the value you determine in the lambda expression and then returns an enumerable.

Your outer call is good for that:

```
_sut.OrderDataArray.OrderBy(o => something).ToArray();
```

You sort by something, and then convert the result into a (then sorted) array. There are two things that matter here: First of all, at least in your example, there is only one object in `OrderDataArray`, so there is no sort happening. Second, it depends on the return value of `something` how those objects are sorted.

So in that case, what is `something`? It’s the following:

```
o.OrderHeaderArray.OrderBy(a => somethingElse)
```

So regardless of `somethingElse`, what does this return? An `IEnumerable<OrderHeader>`. How do multiple enumerables compare to each other? They are not really comparable; and they especially don’t tell you anything about the order based on their *content* (you’d have to enumerate it first). So essentially, you order that `OrderHeaderArray` by “something else”, use the result which does not tell you anything about an order as the key to order the `OrderDataArray`. Then, you throw the sorted `OrderHeaderArray` away.

You do the same exactly one level deeper with the `OrderPositionArray`, which again will not do anything useful. The only actual useful ordering happens to the `OrderPositionArray` itself but that result is again thrown away.

---

Now, if you want to order your structure, you should do so properly, by reassinging the sorted structure to the array. So at some point, you would have to do the following:

```
a.OrderPositionArray = a.OrderPositionArray.OrderBy(p => p.LineNumber).ToArray();
```

But apart from the `OrderPositionArray` itself and the `OrderHeader`, you don’t really have anything that can be sorted (because you can’t really sort a collection by the order of a subcollection). So you could could solve it like this:

```
foreach (OrderData data in _sut.OrderDataArray)
{
    foreach (OrderHeader header in data.OrderHeaderArray)
    {
        header.OrderPositionArray = header.OrderPositionArray.OrderBy(p => p.LineNumber).ToArray();
    }

    data.OrderHeaderArray = data.OrderHeaderArray.OrderBy(h => h.SequenceNumber).ToArray();
}
```

Instead of Linq, you can also sort the arrays in-place, which maybe makes it a bit nicer since you are not creating new inner arrays:

```
var c = Comparer<int>.Default;
foreach (OrderData data in _sut.OrderDataArray)
{
    foreach (OrderHeader header in data.OrderHeaderArray)
    {
        Array.Sort(header.OrderPositionArray, new Comparison<OrderPositions>((x, y) => c.Compare(x.LineNumber, y.LineNumber)));
    }

    Array.Sort(data.OrderHeaderArray, new Comparison<OrderHeader>((x, y) => c.Compare(x.SequenceNumber, y.SequenceNumber)));
}
```

Comment: poke, there is a little error in the code, examples, instead of Array.Sort(a.OrderPositionArray... it should be Array.Sort(header.OrderPositionArray...

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
var ordered = _sut.OrderDataArray.OrderBy(o => ...
```

expects the `Func<OrderData, TKey>`, and the values will be sorted by comparing the result of this function execution.

At the same time, you pass the result of another `OrderBy`, which is `IOrderedEnumerable`. It simply doesn't make much sense.

In order to sort all the nested collections, you can do the following:

```
foreach (var orderData in _sut.OrderDataArray)
{
  foreach (var orderHeader in orderData.OrderHeaderArray)
  {
    orderHeader.OrderPositionArray = orderHeader.OrderPositionArray
        .OrderBy(x => x.LineNumber).ToArray();
  }

  orderData.OrderHeaderArray = orderData.OrderHeaderArray
      .OrderBy(x => x.SequenceNumber).ToArray();
}

_sut.OrderDataArray = _sut.OrderDataArray
    .OrderBy(x => ...).ToArray();
```

It sorts every `OrderPositionArray` item by its items' `LineNumber`.
It sorts every `OrderHeaderArray` by headers' `SequenceNumber`.

However, it is pretty unclear how you want to sort `_sut.OrderDataArray` - it is marked as `x => ...` in the example.
It has no comparable properties which can be used for sorting.